# Correlation attenuation: Question about Spearman’s correction

Tags: correlation, measurement-error, spearman-rho

**Correlation attenuation: Question about Spearman’s correction**

Disclaimer: I’m not a statistician, so please don’t be surprised about ignorance and/or outrageously stupid faults in reasoning. But do let me know, please!

I’m interested in the expected attenuation of a hypothesized correlation by imperfect measures. My motivation is to take this into account for power calculations. For a hypothesized correlation $r_{xy}$ between two properties, what is the expected observed correlation $r_{x’y’}$ between two imperfect measures of these properties? The imperfectness of these measures is given by their validity ($r_{x’x}$ and $r_{y’y}$; their correlation with the property they aim to measure), which in turn can be estimated by their re-test reliabilities ($r_{x'_1x'_2}$ and $r_{y'_1y'_2}$; which really are upper bounds of their validity).

Running some simulations I stumbled upon a simple pattern:

$r_{x’y’} =  r_{xy} \times r_{x'x} \times r_{y'y}$

which – I thought –  surely has been described before. Googleing a bit, I hit on Spearman’s ‘disattenuation’ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_for_attenuation, https://www.jstor.org/stable/1412159).

As far as I see, this is looking at the same thing from the opposite end. Spearman was interested in estimating $r_{xy}$ from $r_{x’y’}$, by correcting for the attenuation effect of $r_{x'_1x'_2}$ and $r_{y'_1y'_2}$. My problem is that his equation is different from my results:

$r_{xy} =  \frac{r_{x’y’}}{\sqrt{r_{x'_1x'_2}\times r_{y'_1y'_2}}}$

which implies

$r_{x’y’} = r_{xy} \times \sqrt{r_{x'_1x'_2}\times r_{y'_1y'_2}}$

Basically, the effect of attenuation in my simulations is the square of that given by Spearman. So I went back and double-checked that my simulations do what I thought they would do. Checking the properties of the simulated data, everything seems to be in order: the simulated ‘true’ values $x$ and $y$ correlate with $r_{xy}$; the measurements $x’$ correlate with $x$ by $r_{xx}$, $y’$ and $y$ correlate by $r_{yy}$. However, $r_{x’y’}$ is equal to $r_{xy}$ attenuated by the product of $r_{x’x}$ and $r_{y’y}$, rather than the square root of that product.

Thinking about this discrepancy, I also noticed that Spearman’s attenuation formula goes against my intuition. Take the simplest case: Two properties that are perfectly correlated ($r_{xy} = 1$), a perfect measure of the criterion ($r_{yy} = 1$) and a measure of the predictor that has limited reliability ($r_{xx} <1$). For this case, my simulations would suggest

$r_{x’y’}= 1\times 1 \times r_{x'x} = r_{x'x}$,

whereas Spearman would predict

$r_{x’y’} = 1 \times \sqrt{1\times r_{x'_1x'_2}} = \sqrt{r_{x'_1x'_2}}$.

I don’t understand how Spearman’s solution makes sense. It implies that the observed correlation of $x’$ with $y’$ will be higher than the correlation of $x’$ with itself ($r_{x'_1x'_2}$). How can that possibly be true? It seems obvious to me, that if $r_{x'_1x'_2}$ is the only limiting factor for $r_{x’y’}$ (because everything else is perfectly correlated), $r_{x’y’}$ should be equal to $r_{x'_1x'_2}$.

So, where do I go wrong? How does the square root in Spearman’s equation make sense? What could explain this discrepancy between his equation and the simulation results?

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to clever facebook friends I think I got it now. The crux is the difference between retest reliability (e.g., $r_{x'_1x'_2}$) and validity ($r_{x'x}$). $r_{xx}$ in Spearman's formula refers to $r_{x'_1x'_2}$. In the original question I used $r_{xx}$ to refer to the validity $r_{x'x}$, as if it were the same thing (notations now edited for clarity).

I did not think of this as a problem, because I assumed reliability to be an upper bound estimate of validity. That turns out to be wrong however. The cap that reliability puts on validity ($r_{x'x_\max}$) is $r_{x'x_\max} = \sqrt{r_{x'_1x'_2}}$.

That is because re-test reliability is affected by twice the measurement error, due to the repetition. The correlation between measures and *true* values is only affected by one instance of the measurement error.