# Simulating an example of correlation attenuation due to measurement error

Tags: r, correlation, reliability, measurement-error, association-measure

I'm trying to simulate an example of the attenuation of an association due to measurement error. According to the attenuation formula from classical test theory, the presence of measurement error attenuates the observed correlation between two variables (assuming random error). That is, the observed correlation is weaker than the true correlation. Here is the attenuation formula (Schmidt & Hunter, 1996):

$r_{xy} = r_{x_ty_t} \sqrt{r_{xx} r_{yy}}$

Using this formula, if the true association (i.e., the association of the true scores) between $x$ and $y$ is $r_{x_ty_t} = .7$, the reliability of $x$ is .9 and the reliability of $y$ is .85, and the measurement error is random, we can estimate that the observed association between $x$ and $y$ will be $r \sim .61$:

$r_{xy} = r_{x_ty_t} \sqrt{r_{xx} r_{yy}} = .7 \times \sqrt{.9 \times .85} = .61$

However, I get a different answer when conducting a simulation. I simulated two variables (`predictor` and `criterion`) that are correlated at $r_{x_ty_t} = .7$. I then created variables for the `predictor` and `criterion` that have measurement error. The extent of measurement error added was selected so that the reliability of the `predictor` (i.e., the correlation of the `predictor` with the corresponding variable with measurement error; $r_{xx}$) is .9 and the reliability of the `criterion` (i.e., the correlation of the `criterion` with the corresponding variable with measurement error; $r_{yy}$) is .85. However, when I calculate the observed association between the `predictor` with measurement error and the `criterion` with measurement error, the observed association is .56.

Here is my simulated example:

```
library("psych")
library("MASS")

#Simulate data so predictor and criterion are correlated ~ r = .7
set.seed(123)
sampleSize <- 1000
means <- c(50, 100)
standardDeviations <- c(10, 15)

correlationMatrix <- matrix(.7, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
diag(correlationMatrix) <- 1
rownames(correlationMatrix) <- colnames(correlationMatrix) <- c("predictor","criterion")

covarianceMatrix <- cor2cov(correlationMatrix, sigma = standardDeviations)

mydata <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n = sampleSize, mu = means, Sigma = covarianceMatrix, empirical = TRUE))

#Create variables with added measurement error
mydata$predictorWithMeasurementError <- mydata$predictor + rnorm(n = sampleSize, mean = 0, sd = 4.91)
mydata$criterionWithMeasurementError <- mydata$criterion + rnorm(n = sampleSize, mean = 0, sd = 9.09)

#Add missing values
missingValuesPredictor <- sample(1:sampleSize, size = 50, replace = FALSE)
missingValuesCriterion <- sample(1:sampleSize, size = 50, replace = FALSE)

mydata$predictor[missingValuesPredictor] <- NA
mydata$criterion[missingValuesCriterion] <- NA
mydata$predictorWithMeasurementError[missingValuesPredictor] <- NA
mydata$criterionWithMeasurementError[missingValuesCriterion] <- NA

#Reliability of Predictor
cor.test(x = mydata$predictor, y = mydata$predictorWithMeasurementError)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  mydata$predictor and mydata$predictorWithMeasurementError
t = 63.589, df = 948, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.8872299 0.9114691
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.9000433 


#Reliability of Criterion
cor.test(x = mydata$criterion, y = mydata$criterionWithMeasurementError)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  mydata$criterion and mydata$criterionWithMeasurementError
t = 49.707, df = 948, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.8314764 0.8668539
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.8501216 


#True Association
cor.test(x = mydata$predictor, y = mydata$criterion)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  mydata$predictor and mydata$criterion
t = 29.645, df = 900, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6682672 0.7344597
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.7028819 


#Effect of measurement error on association: observed association after adding measurement error
cor.test(x = mydata$predictorWithMeasurementError, y = mydata$criterionWithMeasurementError)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  mydata$predictorWithMeasurementError and mydata$criterionWithMeasurementError
t = 20.408, df = 900, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5161443 0.6055132
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.5624693
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is my observed association ($r_{xy} = .56$) less than the expected value of .61?
2. How can I modify my simulated example so that the observed association more closely approximates the expected value (i.e., $r_{xy} \sim .61$)?

Schmidt, F. L., & Hunter, J. E. (1996). Measurement error in psychological research: Lessons from 26 research scenarios. *Psychological Methods*, *1*(2), 199–223. https://doi.org/10.1037/1082-989X.1.2.199

Comment: This may be related to what someone else noted here that "re-test reliability is affected by twice the measurement error, due to the repetition. The correlation between measures and true values is only affected by one instance of the measurement error.": https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/349568/20338